# Why isn't the first code not working, whereas second does?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, sklearn-pandas

First code snippet:

```
imp.fit_transform(dataset['Age'].values.reshape(-1,1))
dataset['Age'] = dataset['Age'].values.reshape(-1,1)
```

Second code snippet:

```
imp.fit(dataset['Age'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
dataset['Age'] = imp.transform(dataset['Age'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

The first code snippet does not make any change to the age column of my dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first code does not change the `Age` column because you are not asking it to do it ;) you apply the `fit_transform` function but you do not use it to change the dataset.

I don't know what is `imp`, but a more correct implementation of the first piece of code would certainly be something like :

```
dataset['Age'] = imp.fit_transform(dataset['Age'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```